# sed split substring that may or may not be present

Tags: sed

Trying to split the column of text based on the text that may or may not be there.

sample file:

```
TEXT1D1NEWBWP210HTEXT2
TEXT1D1BWP210HTEXT2
```

expected output:

```
TEXT1D1NEWBWP210HTEXT2 NEWBWP 210H
TEXT1D1BWP210HTEXT2 BWP 210H
```

cmd used --- Expecting that "?" would check if the substring "NEW" is present and print in case it is there.

```
cat <text_file> | sed -e 's/.*\(\s*\)\(NEW\)\?\(BWP\)\([0-9]\+\)H.*/\0 \2\3 \4H/'
```

Output from the above cmd is

```
TEXT1D1NEWBWP210HTEXT2 BWP 210H
TEXT1D1BWP210HTEXT2 BWP 210H
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU or BSD sed for `-E` so you don't need all those backslashes (you were already using GNU sed for `\s`):

```
$ sed -Ee 's/((NEW)?BWP)([0-9]+)H.*/& \1 \3H/' file
TEXT1D1NEWBWP210HTEXT2 NEWBWP 210H
TEXT1D1BWP210HTEXT2 BWP 210H
```

The main problem with your regexp was the initial `.*` would consume the optional `NEW` if it was present.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(NEWBWP|BWP)([0-9]+H).*/& \1 \2/' file
```

Alternation `|` works from left to right, thus if `NEWBWP` is not matched then `BWP` will be attempted.

Answer (score 2):

> what I am doing wrong here

Ugh, this is going to be hard and is closely related to how regex works. Regex matches from left to right. It matches greedy - matches everything until it can't match any further. Then it goes back and matches the string "from the end". Because it matches ~`BWP` from the end, `NEW` never comes up.

```
.*\(\s*\)\(NEW\)\?\(BWP\)\([0-9]\+\)H.*
                                         Events:
^^                                       - matches everything
    ^^^                                  - matches nothing (end of string)
          ^^^^^^^^                       - matches nothing (end of string)
                    ^^^                  - engine is at the end of string
                                           so it goes back until BWP is matched
^^                                       - matches 'TEXT1D1NEWBWP210HTEXT' (from the back)
                    ^^^                  - does not match
^^                                       - matches 'TEXT1D1NEWBWP210HTEX' (from the back)
                    ^^^                  - does not match
^^                  ^^^                  - ^^^ etc. for each character from the end
^^                                       - matches 'TEXT1D1NEWB' (from the back)
                    ^^^                  - does not match
^^                                       - matches 'TEXT1D1NEW' (from the back)
                    ^^^                  - matches 'BWP'
                        ^^^..            - regex engine continues
```

You can read more at https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy .

Anyway, you have to program it:

```
 $ sed -e '
    s/.*\s*\(NEWBWP\)\([0-9]\+H\).*/\0 \1 \2/;
    t a;  # if the above s was successful, go to a
       s/.*\s*\(BWP\)\([0-9]\+H\).*/\0 \1 \2/;
    : a;
   ' <<<$'TEXT1D1NEWBWP210HTEXT2\nTEXT1D1BWP210HTEXT2'
 TEXT1D1NEWBWP210HTEXT2 NEWBWP 210H
 TEXT1D1BWP210HTEXT2 BWP 210H
```